# while with a noun phrase

Tags: grammar

Can we use 'while' with a noun phrase i.e. with a clause that does not make a complete sentence?

> e.g. We stay home while our kids playing out.

Is this grammatical? Or is it necessary to place stative verb [are] in this?

Like we sometimes drop the subject and verb in the clause of while.

> We run while we have our jumpers on.
>
> We run while our jumpers on.

Comment: No. And "We run while our jumpers on" is not right either. In both of these you need verbs.

Answer (score 1):

> Can we use 'while' with a noun phrase?

Yes. But your examples aren't correct.

---

- We stay home while our kids playing out.

This is wrong because the tenses don't match. It should be:

> We **stay** home while our kids **play** out.

or

> We **stayed** home while our kids **played** out.

---

- We run while we have our jumpers on.

This is grammatically correct, if you intend it to be in the simple present tense. It's a bit weird, because there doesn't seem to be any correlation between wearing jumpers and running. We use "while" to denote that two things happened concurrently, so this sounds like whenever you put your jumpers on, it causes you to run. If you mean to say that you just happened to be wearing your jumpers, or that you put your jumpers on *to* run, you should perhaps instead say:

> We run *with* our jumpers on.

or

> We wear jumpers while running.

---

- We run while our jumpers on.

This is not grammatical. See previous response for the correct grammar.